# Get last id of an entity in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, lastinsertid

I need a way to fetch the last id of an entity in database, let's say for example

Product entity:

I try this but its not working:

```
 public int lastInsertedId() {
        try {
            if (!session.isOpen())
                session = DatabaseUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select last_value from purchase_idpurchase_seq ");

            int lastid = query.getFirstResult();

            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
            return lastid;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Where in the Postgres manual did you find that syntax? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html

Comment: when i execute this query in postgresql : select last_value from purchase_idpurchase_seq,  i get a result, but i don't know to implement this in hibernate

Comment: No, i don't use a certeria

Comment: What does *its not working* mean exactly? It throws a PostgreSQL error? Or other java exception? Or gives zero, or other falsy value?

Comment: it works for me now.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of Googling, i get the solution:

```
 public int lastInsertedId() {
        try {
            if (!session.isOpen())
                session = DatabaseUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Purchase.class);
            c.addOrder(Order.desc("id"));
            c.setMaxResults(1);
            int id = (int) ((Purchase) c.uniqueResult()).getIdPurchase();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
            return id;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }


    }
```

Comment: You **have** to use `currval()` or `lastval()` (the link I already posted in my first comment) to get the recently generated sequence value. Your code is not going to work properly if more than one transaction is modifying the database. Plus: I'm pretty sure Hibernate should be able to do that natively. Isn't there a "SequenceGenerator" annotation for Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:

```
   String hql = "from purchase_idpurchase_seq";
   Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
   List<purchase_idpurchase_seq> results = query.list();
```

And to get the value of `last_value`  try this:

```
  String last_value = results.getLast_value(); //  if getLast_value return int use int.
```

I suppose you have an entity `purchase_idpurchase_seq`

Try to take a look at this [site](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_sessions.htm)

Comment: purchase_idpurchase_seq is sequence in the database, purchase is the entity

Comment: @abdouamer see the link above it's helpful